# Does git checkout --ours affect files that are not in conflict?

Tags: git, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I am rebasing a lot of commits right now, and previously one caused a conflict in two files. I examined those and decide that I can safely use "ours (master)".

So I ran the `git checkout --ours .`, and the conflict files successfully used the master version.

However I just remembered that the commit also contains a few other files (not in conflict). Does my command also checkout the master version for those files (by my mistake)?

Comment: just a headsup abt --ours: git checkout --ours keeps the local version only in the case of rebase. In normal merges, --ours refers to the remote

Comment: See also https://github.com/git/git/commit/f30301657b68561392d910f6196380dd3976549e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick test shows that a `git checkout --ours .` does not change files in the index (i.e. files that were merged cleanly and are ready to be committed).